# Program that uses Selenium to interact with Microsoft Edge is not working in debug mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, browser-automation

I've built a .NET Web App using the MVC model. The Controller has a simple function that opens the Edge Browser and navigates to a particular URL using Selenium. This app works as expected in non-debug mode. However, on running it in debug mode, it opens the Edge browser and the program stops executing without any exception and never navigates to the URL. The same App works perfectly fine in debug as well as non-debug mode when I use the Chrome Driver. I also built a simple console App that does the same thing (open a browser using Selenium & navigate to a URL ) and that too works perfectly. So, there seems to be **some problem while using The Microsoft Edge Driver in a Web App in Debug Mode**. Is there any way to solve the issue ?
The app that I have been written can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiGA4jDm9_mlk2HH6ZqByyzEW-6q).

No error or exception is thrown. Attaching the output from the Debug window, in case it maybe of any help.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager:Information: User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\chat\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 DEBUG http://localhost:55681/  0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44302/
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 37.4489ms 200 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing action MvcMovie.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MvcMovie)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method MvcMovie.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MvcMovie) - Validation state: Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method MvcMovie.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MvcMovie), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 0.7576ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor:Information: Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor:Information: Executed ViewResult - view Index executed in 110.4176ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action MvcMovie.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MvcMovie) in 203.9462ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 384.9252ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44302/HelloWorld/GoToURL
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "GoToURL", controller = "HelloWorld"}. Executing action MvcMovie.Controllers.HelloWorldController.GoToURL (MvcMovie)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method MvcMovie.Controllers.HelloWorldController.GoToURL (MvcMovie) - Validation state: Valid

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with your project but got an error below.
[image]

I suggest you to again check a project on your end and let us know whether it is running or not.

Comment: Did you get this error on build or execution ? The sample project seems to be working on my machine

Comment: Can you clean and then rebuild it once ?